# Google Sheets API

Tags: android, database

Good Morning

I am in the process of developing an Android application for a client, that stores his data in a Google Drive Spreadsheet.

My question is, for pulling the data from the spreadsheet to the Android application, would I need to use the Google Sheets API. I will be pulling certain column data to populate text box controls and passing them back to the spreadsheet.

What would be the most efficient way to do this and id there any tutorials that anyone can point me to, so I can get a feel for accomplishing such a task.

A couple of other things I thought of, if at all possible was storing the data in the local data storage and passing that data to the spreadsheet if that is possible.

Any help or information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options to consider:

- You can publish the sheet to the web and pull the feed dynamically (https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample)
- You can access the sheet programmatically (without an OAuth callback) if you register your app and generate client credentials in your Google console (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount)